# Code Snippet Not Working (Chrome)

Tags: support

When I have attempted to add an HTML / CSS / JS code snippet in the past week using Chrome 54 and 55, the window, as seen below, is entirely empty and allows for no code entry. This takes place with and without an ad-blocker. Selecting to run or insert does nothing, as well. By copy-pasting from old posts, I can create these snippets without the editor, but this is far too time-consuming and does not allow for easily testing the code before posting.

On the other hand, Microsoft Edge works perfectly fine and displays all four boxes as normal.

What is the cause of this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the latest version (55.0.2868.0) of [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html?platform=win64), the nightly build of Chrome.

However, the (currently) most recent Dev branch release, 55.0.2859.0, is still affected by this bug.