# I can't insert snippets on Chrome, Ubuntu, as of today (8 may `17)

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, google-chrome

I read existing questions on errors for inserting code snippet in answers but they were all duplicated to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334716/code-snippet-not-working-chrome) which states the issue is fixed. Besides, I wasn't able to find another question featuring the error posted below (or similar).

My problem started happening today and <del>as of this point</del> I can't insert snippets in [so] answers using Chrome `Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)` on Ubuntu.

Here's the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined
    at i (cdn.sstatic.net/Js/snippet-javascript.en.js?v=8949a8564319:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (cdn.sstatic.net/Js/snippet-javascript.en.js?v=8949a8564319:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at e (stub.en.js:1)
```

Notes:

1. I can insert snippets in answers using Firefox.
2. The issue also happens when I try to edit an existing snippet (on clicking the "*Save & insert into post*" button). After getting the error, the "*Cancel*" button stops working too. I need to reload the page in order to exit snippet. "*Run*" and "*Add an external library*" buttons still work.
3. Trying to do some more testing, I found (some older) answers which were not triggering the bug and assumed it only happens on some questions. Going back to questions where I experienced it, it no longer happens there either. So...

For the past 8-9 minutes, I was no longer able to reproduce the bug.
**Should I delete the question?**

Please advise.

Comment: My advice is to (temporarily at least) [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: @Giant, you seem to have been right. Happened again today. Closed, Opened in incognito, singed in and I was good to go. Consider adding your comment as an answer. Besides being up-lifting, it might actually help others experiencing this bug.

Comment: If it continues to happen, it might be a problem.  Do you have any user scripts or extensions installed?

Comment: I had a few extensions: VirtualHosts, AdBlocker, GoToMeetingScreensharing and PrettyBeautfulJavascript. PBJ and VH haven't used in quite a while. Suspect AdBlocker might cause problems but I use it frequently against what I build. Disabled all for now and I'll just see if it still happens. Thanks.